# spinner is giving me an error , i am not able to resolve it

Tags: java, android, constructor

Here is code!when i run this. It gives errors in logcat. I have provided logcat below.Please check! Help me how to resolve this error.

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

//error 1//
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Automobile");
list.add("Business Services");
list.add("Computers");
list.add("Education");
list.add("Personal");
list.add("Travel");

//error2//
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list); 

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

**i am getting an error which i am not able to solve on my own . i need help regarding these errors **

**errors**

```
1.(85, 37) error: method setOnItemSelectedListener in class AdapterView<T> cannot be applied to given types;
required: OnItemSelectedListener
found: <anonymous OnClickListener>
reason: actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to OnItemSelectedListener by method invocation conversion
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Adapter declared in class AdapterView

2.Error:(95, 64) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous OnClickListener>,int,List<String>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

***here is the code of onClickListner***

```
button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    CheckBox yes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes);
                    CheckBox no = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no);
                    EditText ageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageText);
                    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);


                    String name = editText.getText().toString();


                    if (yes.isChecked()) {
                        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                        int c;
                        c = age - 7;
                        int z;
                        z = 2016 + c;

                        editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year " + z) + "");

                    } else if (no.isChecked()) {
                        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                        int c;

                        c = age + 10;
                        int z;
                        z = 2016 + c;
                        editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year " + z) + "");
```

Comment: can further guide you if u post the code with your OnClickListener.

Comment: Dont downvote, It seems like Stackoverflow is getting harsher everyday with beginners

Comment: yes that is right :( i get error in every question and get blocked :(

Comment: @DeBuGGeR  done , you can see the code of onClickListener

Comment: post your  `onItemSelected` method

Comment: @kapilrajput  
second error is left now please help me

Answer (score 0):

It cant be plainer than its shown in logcat.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

should be

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(MyActivity.this);
```

Comment: yes, whatever activity your spinner is in. Please read more on scopes and anonymous classes in java to grab this concept completely.

Comment: yea , the spinner is in the main activity "activity_main" now when i write this is get an error  **cannot resolve the symbol activity_main**

Comment: MainActivity not activity_main

Answer (score 0):

If your Activity is implementing OnItemSelectedListener interface then you can pass context to spinner item click listener.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Otherwise, pass an anonymous class instance which implements OnItemSelectedListener interface.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

---

**Error 2 :**

You might be trying to initialize your adapter inside an anonymous class. Pass **[YourActivityName].this** instead of **this** to the constructor of ArrayAdapter.

Read more about spinners [Android - Spinner Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm)

Comment: first error solved , now please help in solving second error :) .

Comment: The problem is , you might be passing wrong context to array adapter. Pass the context of your activity. Let's say , if your activity's name is "MyActivity" then the initialization would be :
`ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list); `